# How can I tag questions so that they can be easily found with search engines later?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, etiquette, search-engine

I've searched for this question tons of times [How to get the biggest numbers out from huge amount of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218922/how-to-get-the-biggest-numbers-out-from-huge-amount-of-numbers) but every time I do, I start with Google searches like "python multiple max", "python max x values", etc., none of which turn up very useful results.

This seems like it qualifies as "the good information is buried under a sea of bad information" as described [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), which makes me think that I should just create a question and answer it myself that will point me in the right direction. But it seems strange to ask a question just to put some key words in the title, pray that it shows up at the top of Google searches, and have it point in the right direction.

Any thoughts? Is there another way to "tag" a question in a way that increases the ability of myself/others to find the question/answer by Googling or searching within SO later? (Obviously I know that SO questions have a tagging system, but I'm not sure that that is the solution I'm looking for here.)

I also know I can favorite, etc. the question to help myself find it later, but I want to help other people looking for the same information.

Comment: The existing tag system is your best bet for this. So is editing the question to improve the title. Strive for titles that very much resemble the natural language question that someone (yourself?) might enter into a search engine. Questions on SO get indexed by Google *extremely* quickly, so the problem is just getting the question itself to jive with the common search terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great point!

Either retag the question, or edit the question so it contains more of the relevant search terms.

Joel Spolsky was complaining about some iPhone programming example that someone forwarded him, and the answer is really the same -- *be the change you want to see, man!*

That is, edit the question / answers to have a great title and better, more descriptive post bodies that cover the terms you'd *expect* to find in a search.

Remember, we allow completely anonymous editing ...

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

... so anyone and everyone is empowered to fix these issues.